# Google Maps API for Android Needs a new api key or need to activated if the android studio is run on a new PC

Tags: android, google-maps

I've been using Google Maps SDK for Android. I've recently used the Google Map API. Each time i run on a different PC.The MAP just does'nt work and it gets resolved if i go and create or instantiate a new API key. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create new APi key only add or update sha1 key because for debug build sha1 is different on different PC. For reference
Click [here](https://www.journaldev.com/10365/android-google-maps-api)!